# Spring boot - how to load credentials from aws secret manger in inject properties into spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-ecs

I want to inject database connection propertiy values, and others from AWS Secret Manager. (Something similary with [this solution](https://bmuschko.com/blog/docker-secret-spring-boot/)). So they can be read in an implementation of `EnvironmentPostProcessor` and injected into spring like this:

```
 props.put("spring.datasource.username", usernameValue);
 props.put("spring.datasource.password", passwordValue);
 environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("dbProps", props));
```

However, to accomplish this, I need an instance of AwsSecretManagerClient which can be obtained only after initializing properties.
Which is the best solution to accomplish this? (and maybe a best practice)

**Note:** Application will be running in docker in AWS ECS, and the accessKey/secretKey will be different on each environment.

Comment: Why not use the Secrets Manager integration available in ECS to inject those values as environment variables in the container? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/secrets-envvar-secrets-manager.html

Comment: I don't want to have a long list of environment variables. I prefer injecting then programatically. I don't know if is the best option, but is for learning purposes.

Comment: It's not clear where you are stuck exactly. Are you just saying you need an AWS access key/secret key so that you can initialize `AwsSecretManagerClient`? If that's the case, then you are doing AWS IAM Authentication on ECS wrong. You should be assigning an ECS Task Role (in addition to the Task Execution Role) to your ECS task, with the appropriate permissions for accessing secrets manager. The AWS Java SDK will automatically pick up that role and use it when you initialize an SDK client without any explicit credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a potential chicken-egg problem here. You have a Spring Boot application that has application properties that you want to inject. You want these values to come from AWS Secrets Manager and you are using AWS ECS.

This will not work without a custom, non-standard solution.

In either case, you will need a properly configured Execution Task Role or Task Role in your ECS Task Definition to even allow you to get the value from AWS Secrets.

If you were really determined to inject it in as a property, you would have to do that BEFORE you invoke your SpringApplication in your main method. In this case, your Task Role would need Secrets access so you can use the AWS SDK to get them. This is a lot of pre-start code and is just a bit awkward when there are tools readily available to do this for you. I can imagine something like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //write a bunch of code to instantiate the AwsSecretManagerClient
        //and then pull out the values, to then put as properties.
        //this code also has to account for when you are not running on AWS

        //then start your Spring application
    }
```

The suggested method here is to just use ECS to inject them for you.

For example, let's say you have `spring.datasource.password` in your application properties (or yaml). The value is stored in a AWS Secret named `DBPassword` and you want to use the Secrets value at runtime on ECS.

Your Task Definition should have a section like this

```
     "secrets": [
              
                {
                    "name": "SPRING_DATBASOURCE_PASSWORD",
                    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:{{region}}:{{accountNumber}}:secret:DBPassword"
                }
         
            ],
```

For this to happen, your Task Definition should have the Execution Role with permission:

```
        {
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:{{region}}:{{accountNumber}}:secret:DBPassword",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
```

From there. You don't need to do anything else in your Spring application. Spring will override your application.yml/properties value based on the new environment variable that was set for you via ECS.

The beauty of this solution is that you don't need special code. Locally, you can develop with your application.yaml/properties and then in ECS, with a little infrastructure configuration, you get it auto-overwritten. No extra complex code to handle both local and AWS.

Comment: This solution sounds very well to me. Thanks.